# Branding Advance search box of sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, branding, custom-masterpage, enterprise-search

I have created custom master page using html and design manager. Now as per my html in below design. I want to redesign search box as below which will open on click on search Icon.

[image: Customize search box design]

As I am new in Branding of sharepoint 2013 . Anyone please assist me how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Set  ***Display:none***  to outer div of Search box by default. so when page will load it will not show on UI.

And use Jquery ***Hide()*** and ***Show()*** to toggle it.

Comment: I done with that hide show code i have jquery & html but i want to use it as a advance search box. I don't know how to do that. Will you please share the steps for that?